# Animate with scrollview

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview

I am trying to animate the position of 2 buttons on a scroll view I have.

My scrollview has 2 views, an inbox showing messages and a user button showing the user settings/profile.

What I am trying to accomplish is a smooth animation with the scrollview. I have detected the scrollviews content offset and call the animation based on the position of the scrollview inside `scrollViewDidScroll`

I have the animation partially working however I dont want to animate with duration I want to animate based on the scroll position so that the buttons move with the scroll (either to the left or the right).

```
if currentX < width {
    print("This is the message screen")

    self.msgIconRightConstraint.constant = scrollView.bounds.width/2 - 15
    self.profileIconRightConstraint.constant = 10

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)

} else {
    print("This is the settings screen")

    self.msgIconRightConstraint.constant = scrollView.bounds.width - 45
    self.profileIconRightConstraint.constant = scrollView.bounds.width/2 - 15

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Comment: So the buttons aren't moving with the scrollview? Couldn't you just make them subviews of the scrollview? Or are you trying to have them move independently in a way related to the scrollview? Sorry if I am misunderstanding...

Comment: Inside my scroll view I am placing 2 view controllers with paging enabled (think of the way snapchat works swiping to different states of the app). My thinking was to get the contentOffset.x of the scrollview and move the position of the buttons (via constraints) to reflect the content of the scrollview. However I havent worked out how to do the animation with a gesture instead of with duration

Comment: Where are the buttons located exactly? In which view?

Comment: I have one ViewController (AppVC), the top 70 pixels is a View with my two buttons. The rest of that view is a UIScrollView, this is what the screen shot represents. In my code I have made the scrollView 2X the width of the views bounds. Inside the scrollView I am injecting 2 view controllers side by side. The user can scroll horizontally (left - to - right) to either access there message inbox or settings

Comment: So you want the buttons to slide with the scrollview?

Comment: When the content offset is 0, the messages icon is in the middle. Since paging is enabled when the user scrolls the scrollView will snap in place once its scroll to the next page. During this scroll I want to change the position of the buttons so that the settings is in the middle and the messages are on the far left of the menu

Comment: @Lahav yes I want the buttons to slide with the scrollview

Comment: Additionally I will change the background color to reflect the current selected state

Comment: Wait so why don't you just make them both part of the same scrollview?

Comment: My scrollview is paged, so if I swipe to the next page both of the buttons would disappear, I could do an animation to change the x position of the buttons but it still doesnt change the fact that I need to animate only during the scroll instead of with duration.

Comment: So rather than using animateWithDuration, why dont you go into the scrollviewdidscroll() method for your scrollview, check the contentoffset.x, and then do the math to see how far your buttons should shift based on how far the scrollview has moved, and then manually set the position of each button by saying button.frame.origin.x = <...>. This will look like a perfectly smooth animation.

Comment: @Lahav it took me a while to do the math behind your idea, but I did get it! thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! Good luck with the rest of your project (: